# Creating model for groups of users in node js Web Application

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am creating an application that should allow users to create or join a group with other users. Every user in a group will have access to some common information. The users are currently stored in a Postgres database with attributes: name and email. I am trying to create a model for groups that would contain a list of authorized users that can access its material.

One approach I thought of was creating a new table in the database consisting of rows of groups and each group had a column: 'authorized_users' which contained an array. However, I read that this is bad practice in SQL.

Another approach would be to create a new table each time a group is created and store the authorized users in that table.

I was looking for help to see if there is an API for node that already performs this, or if any of you have suggestions on how to implement this group model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a new table that keeps the *users in groups* info, modelling a [many to many](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)) relationship:

`users_groups`:

- `user_id`,
- `group_id`,
- (optional) can_read, can_write, etc